# Matching a property string from an array of keywords

Tags: regex, powershell, keyword, scom

I am working on a SCOM script to sort alerts based on MonitoringObjectName , 
Since there are servers with different names , I want to match this (MonitoringObjectName) property string against a list of keywords.
I was wondering how can I match the property against the keywords placed in an array

```
$keywords = @("ABC","DEF","XYZ","GHI")
Get-SCOMAlert | ? ($_.MonitoringObjectName -like "*$keyword*"
```

Looking for ideas/hints how this can be done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use a regular expression match like this:

```
$keywords = 'ABC|DEF|XYZ|GHI'
Get-SCOMAlert | ? { $_.MonitoringObjectName -match $keywords }
```

alternatively (if you want to keep the keywords as a list):

```
$keywords = 'ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ', 'GHI'
$re = $keywords -join '|'
Get-SCOMAlert | ? { $_.MonitoringObjectName -match $re }
```

or do a wildcard comparison in a nested `Where-Object`:

```
$keywords = 'ABC', 'DEF', 'XYZ', 'GHI'
Get-SCOMAlert | ? {
  $name = $_.MonitoringObjectName
  $keywords | ? { $name -like "*$_*" }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response , My scenario is that the keywords are part of server names not the entire server names  itself , so I want to get result only when the full server name is matched against the keyword eg: 
  MonitoringObjectName = ServeABC001" should be a hit becuase ABC is a keyword.

Comment: -Like uses [Regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) so ServeABC001 would get selected because of ABC

Comment: The third solution seems to work for me but where would I add one more condition the existing one ? 
-and $_.ResolutionState -eq "0"  Where would this one fir in ?

Comment: I was incorrect on -like i was thinking of -match. however like checks if the string contains the requested value.

Comment: Use -and to create more complex logic

Comment: @NickYoung I tried this but this is kinda failing 
Get-SCOMAlert | ? {$name = $_.NetbiosComputerName
$key | ? { $name -like "*$_*" }
 -and $_.ResolutionState -eq "0"}

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100527/discussion-between-fenomatik-and-nick-young).

Comment: @Fenomatik For partial matches with the `-like` operator you *must* use wildcards (`$name -like "*$_*"`).

Comment: { ($name -like "*$_*") -and ($_.ResolutionState -eq "0") }

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Your solution was simple and it worked , thanks . Does this approach look efficient to you ?
`Get-SCOMAlert | ?{$_.ManagementGroupId -eq "d88b7cb3-79a8-a82c-3e5e-47adc05fc958"} |  ? {$name = $_.NetbiosComputerName ;$key | ? { $name -like "*$_*" }}`

Comment: @Fenomatik Looks OK to me.

Comment: @NickYoung `-like "$_"` (without wildcards) is the same as `-eq "$_"`.

Comment: Your correct, i missed the wild cards. I usually use match so i misspoke.